# Daily countdown ticker php

Tags: php

Does anyone have an idea how to  make a countdown ticker that shows the hours and mins left until a perticular time of day and on a weekend (Sat and Sun) the time left until 16:30 on Monday. It would need to reset @ 16:30 everyday except the weekend days.

This has got me stumpped and really could do with some pointers.

Thanks,
B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the page to count down every second, rather than only on refresh, you should use JavaScript.  There are many [examples](http://scripts.franciscocharrua.com/countdown-clock.php) out there, and others can be found using google by searching for Javascript Countdown

If you wanted to do it in PHP, the best way is to use [mktime()](http://uk.php.net/mktime) to get the unix timestamp of when the time ends, and the value from [time()](http://uk.php.net/time).

Find the difference, and then you can calculate the time left:

```
$diff = mktime(...) - time();

$days = floor($diff/60/60/24);
$hours = floor(($diff - $days*60*60*24)/60/60);
```

etc.

**EDIT**

Javascript...

Basic idea of the [date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

```
var date = new Date(); //gets now
var weekday = date.getDay(); //gets the current day

//0 is Sunday. 6 is Saturday
if ( weekday == 0 ){
    date.setTime()(date.getTime()+60*60*24); //increase time by a day
}
if (  weekday == 6 ){
    date.setTime()(date.getTime()+60*60*24*2); //increase time by two days
}

//need to check if we have already passed 16:30, 
if ( ( date.getHours() == 16 && date.getMinutes() > 30 ) || date.getHours() > 16){
    //if we have, increase the day
    date.setTime()(date.getTime()+60*60*24)
}

date.setHours(16);
date.setMinutes(30);

//now the date is the time we want to count down to, which we can use with a jquery plugin
```

Comment: Ok so JS is looking like  the way to go...im not very versed in JS how would I do this especily the weekend bit...?

Comment: The javascript section shown here relies on the users clock, not your servers clock, so may not be 100% accurate.  Also, any countdown you start with javascript and use the server time will lose accuracy over time as a 1 second timer in js is not precise.

Answer (score 0):

Would be JQUery also a solution? Because there are several [plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/Countdown+type%3Aproject_project) avalaible which are showing a countdown. With some additional code you could easily calculate the time till the next monday, 4:30 pm.

Comment: Yep I would be up for a bit of JQuery