# PHP Countdown and To Do

Tags: php

I have a few questions. I need a countdown to 17:00 (5 PM) each day. After 17:00, i want to echo a message. Then, the timer needs to reset after 23.59. How can i do this with PHP?

My next question is about a To Do list. I have a functional ToDo list in PHP, but i want to be able to see how many tasks i have without needing to count them myself. Below is the code i have of the To Do list:

```
<?php
session_start();


#ADD ITEM

if(isset($_POST['newitem']) ){
$_SESSION['todo'] [] =$_POST['newitem'];

}


#REMOVE ITEM

if(isset($_POST['remove_id']) ){
    $id = $_POST['remove_id'];
unset($_SESSION['todo'][$id]);

}

?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<?php


echo "<h1>To Do</h1>";


#SUBMIT

echo "
<form action='' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='newitem'>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
";


foreach($_SESSION['todo'] as $id => $item){


#REMOVE

echo "
    <form action='' method='post'>
    <input type ='hidden' name='remove_id' value='$id'>
    <input type='submit'  value='-'>
    $item
    </form>
    ";

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi Patrik, would you be so kind to edit and separate the questions? E.g. one for the time problem, one for the tasks issue. Additionally, have you checked for [solutions on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825283/daily-countdown-ticker-php?rq=1) ?

Comment: Of course, i apologize! I will do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your 2nd question :

You could define an index let's call it `$i`;

So :

```
$i = 0;
```

Then increment it everytime the foreach is executed :

```
foreach($_SESSION['todo'] as $id => $item){

$i++;  

echo "
    <form action='' method='post'>
    <input type ='hidden' name='remove_id' value='$id'>
    <input type='submit'  value='-'>
    $item
    </form>
    ";

}
```

Then `echo $i;` should give you your total of tasks.

Also please put one question at a time en recreate another post with what you've tried for your first question.

Comment: Hmm. That does not seem to work. It echos out the number i define $i as, not incrementing it does nothing. Does it matter where i define it or echo it?

Comment: Ah, i echoed it above the incrementing, which did not work. When i echoed it out below the incrementing/foreach, it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked, dont forget to put your question as resolved ;)